# Where does this relation between gamma, energy and mass come from?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I am doing a course that has used this relation a few times now:

\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{E}{mc^2}
\end{equation}

It makes sense physically, when $E = mc^2$ the particle is at rest and $\gamma =1$. I'm just frustrated that I can't derive it from other formulas. Could any one show me where it comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build up four-momentum from the mass and the four-velocity:

$$m \vec u = m \gamma (\vec e_t + \vec v)$$

But four-momentum can always be decomposed according to energy and momentum:

$$m \vec u = E \vec e_t + \vec p$$

Equate the $t$-components. Done.